# Confused about dimension of direct sum?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I'm trying to review a book before my undergraduate linear algebra class, and I can't understand why the following theorem only applies to finite-dimensional vector spaces.

$Dim(A \oplus B)=Dim(A)+Dim(B)$

Why can't we say a similar thing about infinite dimensional vector spaces? Surely, if $C$ is a basis for $A$, and $D$ is a basis for $B$, then wouldn't $C \cup D$ be a basis for their direct sum?

Comment: We can, using cardinal arithmetic. It's just not a very interesting result if either Dim(A) or Dim(B) is infinite because then Dim(A)+Dim(B)=max (Dim(A),Dim(B)).

Comment: That is true,except  when a space is a subspace of another and both  have the same dimension, the subspace is not necessarily equal to the full space. Thus, this relation is much less useful for infinite dimensional spaces.

Comment: It should say  the disjoint union of C and D ...(in the Q).

Comment: Right, thanks for the clarification guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation you quote is a special case of the more general **Grassman Formula**
$$
\dim(A+B)+\dim(A\cap B)=\dim(A)+\dim(B).
$$

A typical application of the formula is that one can use it to compute one of the numbers in it when the other 3 are known.

The formula is still true when one of, or both the subspaces are infinite dimensional, but in this application the application method fails.